# BufferedReader on Android cutting off my HTTP Post?

Tags: android, http, http-post, bufferedreader

Using a basic Http Post example,

```
try {
    // Construct data
    String data = URLEncoder.encode("param", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(param, "UTF-8");
    data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("param", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(param, "UTF-8");
    data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("param", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(param, "UTF-8");
    data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("param", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(param, "UTF-8");

    // Send data
    URL url = new URL("URL THAT IM SEARCHING");
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.write(data);
    wr.flush();

    // Get the response
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    json = rd.readLine();
    Log.d("TAG",json);
    wr.close();
    rd.close();
} catch (Exception e) { }
```

My response is shortened in android vs the response that I would get running it outside android or even in my browser greatly.

The size of the max response within android is ~4070 bytes vs its actual 14,000+.

I've tried setting my buffer size to 14200 and the response has still stayed the same.

Edit new code below (switched to https & tried suggested solution), still getting ~4070 bye response

```
String getUrl = ("https:.asdadasd/"+trimmed+"?latitude="+lat+"&longitude="+lng+"&distance="+rad);
        Log.d("TAG","URL USED FOR SEARCHING: "+getUrl);
        HttpClient client = new MyHttpClient(getApplicationContext());
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(getUrl);
        HttpResponse responseGet = null;
        try {
        responseGet = client.execute(get);
        HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();    
        InputStream instream = resEntityGet.getContent();

        String result= convertBrToString(instream);
        json = result;
        instream.close();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
        Log.d("TAG", json);

        }
  public String convertBrToString(InputStream in) 
  {

          BufferedReader br;
          StringBuffer outString = new StringBuffer();
          br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in)); 
          try {
              String read;
              read = br.readLine();
          while(read != null)
          {
              outString.append(read);
              read =br.readLine();
          }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
          return outString.toString();     
  }
```

Comment: Any one else have a suggestion!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I never had to do the conversion!  a simple

```
    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler=new BasicResponseHandler();
            String responseBody = client.execute(get, responseHandler);
```

Did the trick, but the problem is that Log will only print out 4096bytes, and that my json parser was getting the length of the wrong array!

Thank you for all your support everyone, & remember to double check your code!